# Deploying REST services using Springboot: whitelabel error

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to learn to deploy a simple REST service using SpringBoot. Below are the class files I am using.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        int a= 5;
        int b=10;
        Addition.addR(a, b);
        }
}
```

and

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/spring/examples")
public class Addition {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public static String addR(int a, int b){
        String c ;
        c= a + b + " = Addition of two Numbers";
        return c;
        }
}
```

When I run the main class, I get an error :

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
```

Any pointers as to whats causing it?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you get an error page just by starting the main class. Because this `Whitelabel Error Page` is the default response of an error page from spring. So you will get this page after a request.

Change your `addR` code like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public static String addR(int a, int b) {
     String c = a + b + " = Addition of two Numbers";
     return c;
 }
```

and send a request like this: `http://localhost:8080/spring/examples?a=1&b=2`. The expected response should then looks so: `3 = Addition of two Numbers`.

And if you want to check if your main class also works just print it on console `System.out.println(Addition.addR(1, 3));`